# Does a vpn software operate on a level where it encrypts data before it leaves your computer?

Tags: vpn

If someone decided to exploit your wifi network, but you have a vpn, do they see data before the vpn software encrypts or after?

Comment: VPN is a tunnel between you and the hosts you want to communicate with, that means your traffic will always be encrypted. The only time it will be unencrypted is before the tunnel is formed.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is complicated by the details.

Remember:

- Open wifi isn't encrypted
- WPA2-PSK is encrypted but it isn't difficult at all for anybody who also knows the passphrase to decrypt (https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11)
- Although the content of HTTPS is encrypted, considerable traffic analysis is available from just what sites you visit, DNS leakage etc
- HTTPS Web proxies can sometimes help with that

I presume you don't mean a site-to-site VPN such as from a small office to HQ, which would normally be WPA2 to the access point, then encrypted in the tunnel to HQ.

A VPN on your laptop will be tunnelled before the wifi, so what the eavesdropper sees is lots of WPA2 packets from your laptop to VPN peer.

**It will be encrypted ONLY if the VPN is set to use encryption.**  Most are, but many are just for addressing convenience.  In many kinds of laptop-based VPN, encryption is an option, which you need to make sure is enabled.

While I'm here: many don't know that one kind of "encryption" available in HTTPS is "NULL" -- all the trappings of SSL are there but there isn't any encryption.  (Eg look up aNULL and eNULL in Apache SSL configs.)  Most web servers are set up to use good encryption only, but if they made a mistake, and your laptop negotiates NULL encryption then the data is naked.

So you could have WPA2, a VPN from your laptop and be on an HTTPS web site and still have no (practical) encryption.

The truth is often an empirical matter: packet sniffing on your laptop before and after the VPN is sometimes the only way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the setup is. I assume you have a VPN client installed on your computer. If that is the case all traffic will be encrypted before it leaves your computer.